# How to open Network share Project in Netbeans

Tags: networking, netbeans, samba, ubuntu-14.04

recently i have install Ubuntu 14.04 and netbeans 8.0,
    i have tried to open net-beans project folder which shares from a windows PC,but i it doesn't shows in /.gvfs shows in other editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type the path to that folder into `File Name` field of file chooser dialog used to open a project and then select a folder underneath it.

Personally I wouldn't recommend this approach. It is better to share your sources using a version control (there are free hosting servers for this). Sharing the source using samba means that you will have to deal with some problems: file endings is one of them. Slower NetBeans will be another because NetBeans tracks file changes using Java NIO watchers and IIRC this doesn't work for mounted folders of this type.